# Placed unnecessary repetitive reference code for Jquery/JavaScript files in order to make jquery Validation plugin work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Here is the information about my development environment:

- Bootstrap v3.3.5

•Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

•.NET Framework 4.6

•ASP.NET MVC assembly System.Web.Mvc Version=5.2.3.0

•MongoDB.Driver 2.0.1.27

•Mongodb 3.0.6

- jquery 1.10.2
- Jquery Validate Plugin
- Jquery Unobtrusive Validate

In my application, I only want Client-side Validation using JQuery Validate Plugin

In bundleconfig.cs, I have the following code:

```
               bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                         "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Also, here is all my ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper code section that renders the form containing all the fields that I want to validate:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EnterCarDetails", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post,        new { @id = "carDtForm", @name = "carDtForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CarName, new { htmlAttributes =                 new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarName, "", new {        @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelName, new {      htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelName, "", new            { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
              </div>
          </div>
       </div> @*end of div class form-horizontal*@
 } @* End BeginForm EnterCarDetails Home *@
```

My Client-side Validation using jQuery Validation Plugin works properly, but the code required to make it work seems to be really unnecessary repetition.

In my _Layout.cshtml , I had to place script tags referring to the jquery, jquery validate plugin file and jquery validate unobtrusive javascript file following code at the very top:

```
     < !DOCTYPE html >
      < html >
< head >
    <   meta charset="utf-8" />
    <   meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"  >
            <  title  >@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

          <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 ....blah blah....
```

Moreover, at the very end of my Index.cshtml , I have the following code:

```
 @section Scripts
 {

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

  }
```

It's seems like it's unnecessary Repetition to have
1) the script tags referring to the jquery, jquery validate plugin file and jquery validate unobtrusive javascript file  in the _Layout.cshtml file
2) the Razor script render for /bundles/jqueryval is placed at the very end of my Index.cshtml

Why do I have to place both references to the jquery/JavaScript files in my applications for the Client-Validation code to work?

Comment: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` includes `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. Remove them from you `<head>` section (your just adding duplicates).

Comment: Thx, but I've have to place all references to JavaScript and/or JQuery within the head tag set enclosed section at the very top of the _Layout.cshtml View?  Is the aforementioned placement a good practice?

Comment: Why do you think you need to place them in the `<head>`?. You can (and there are arguments for and against), but you can also place them immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (which is what your `@section Scripts` section will be doing and is what the MVC developers recommend). As it is, your duplicating them.

Comment: I tried placing the following JavaScript/JQuery references below </body> :     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") @RenderSection("MyScripts", required: false) ,  However, my jQuery Validation fails to work.   If I place it in the <head> </head> set tag section then the jQuery Validation works properly.  But, I want to follow best practices.  How can I keep in line with good practices?

Answer (score 4):

It's not needed to place same references in both _Layout and Index. Make your bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

and preferred to place it in _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Hope this will work fine.